# Overriding standard object to Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, standard-objects, standardcontroller

I'm trying to override the standard page to a custom visualforce page and as you see in the screen shot I do not see the page that I have created, what I'm missing?

`SETUP-->CUSTOMIZE-->ACCOUNTS-->BUTTONS, LINKS AND ACTIONS--> then EDIT LIST`

[image]

Here is my VFP:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account" extensions="AccCtrlExt" tabStyle="Account">

   <apex:enhancedList type="Account" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" id="AccountList"/>
 <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
         //....
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class AccCtrlExt
{    
    public AccCtrlExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
    } 
}
```

Comment: so the page i want to override is the home page of an `Account Object`

Comment: What type of button you used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to override the `List` action, you must use a `StandardSetController`, which you introduce with the `recordSetVar` attribute.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts">
```